# Getting View after fragmentTransaction.Replace()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have an activity with two fragments in it (both dynamically created), one of which is a ListFragment.  I have implemented an onListItemClick handler in the activity.  When an item is clicked, I want to replace both fragments with other fragments, and populate a TextView.  However, after replacing the fragments I can't seem to get the View object I need to manipulate the TextView in the new Details fragment -- it returns null.  Here is some relevant code (onListItemSelected is the handler that processes onListItemClick in the main activity).

```
@Override
public void onListItemSelected(int index) {
    inflateCheckinFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        cif = new checkInFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.action_container, cif, "ACTIONS");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit()

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fm.beginTransaction();
        gdf = new GeolocDetailsFragment();
        fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.fragment_container, gdf, "DETAILS");
        fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction2.commit();

    View gdfView = gdf.getView();

    TextView tv = (TextView)  gdfView.findViewById(R.id.textPOI);
    tv.setText(printPOI(poiList.get(index)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just setting up the data in the onListItemSelected method.  selectedPOI is a private class member.

```
public void onListItemSelected(int index) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.action_container, cif, TAG_CHECKIN);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, gdf, TAG_DETAILS);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        selectedPOI = poiList.get(index);
    }
```

Then in the GeolocDetailsFragment class, I set up a handler to be called in the Activity in the Fragment's onCreateView method to set the TextView value.

```
public class GeolocDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextSetter textSetter;

    public interface TextSetter {
        public String getActivityText();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.geoloc_details_fragment, container, false);
        TextView detailsText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPOI);

        detailsText.setText(textSetter.getActivityText());

        return view;
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            textSetter = (TextSetter) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnGetPOIListener");
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, I implemented getActivityText() in the main activity to get the string to pass to the TextView.

```
    @Override
    public String getActivityText() {

        return printPOI(selectedPOI);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the Fragments in a fashion like this, making the `TextView` public in your fragment helps the `Activity` to access it directly, and there fore change the value.

```
Class GeolocDetailsFragment extends Fragments{

public TextView tv;

onCreateView(){

    tv= (TextView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.textPOI);

    }


}
```

//IN YOUR ACTIVITY

```
@Override
public void onListItemSelected(int index) {

      gdf = new GeolocDetailsFragment();
      gdf.tv.setText(printPOI(poiList.get(index)));

}
```

Comment: It still shows up as null in the onListItemSelected.  In fact, the fragment does not seem to be "active" until onListItemSelected completes its execution.

Comment: have you used `setArguments()` and implemented `Parceleable` on your Activity?, you need to pass the activity instance to get the fragment, so that it can transfer the call back to fragment